# how to change date when system hit midnight or user change time manual cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a problem with my calendar app for mac os x. i write the code and its work fine but as other part of code i want to change the icon of my app when system time hit midnight or user change the system date from system preferences. my code is like this for getting day from date :

```
- (int)dayNumber {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                        initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierPersian];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fa_IR"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:dateFormatter.locale];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:calendar];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d"];
NSString *dayNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]];
int a = [dayNum intValue];

NSLog(@"%i", a);
return a;

}
```

I'm returning an int value because in my other section i have function which have switch command that check this int to changing icon set.

by the way if user change the day from system preferences when app is run and after that close the app and run the app again the app work just fine and detect the current day.

how can i detect if system or user changing day so i can change my app day too.

Comment: You need to review the WWDC video on Calendrical Calculations. There are real potential problems with relying on midnight as a point of reference.

Answer (score 0):

When the system clock is changed, the system posts a notification, `NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification`, which you can observe using the `NSNotficationCenter`.

To know when the date has changed just due to the passage of time, you can use a timer. Compute the fire date for the timer as the beginning of the next day:

```
NSDateComponents* dayComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit
                                              fromDate:[NSDate date]];
dayComponents.day++;
NSDate* startOfTomorrow = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but could you be more specific I'm new to objective-c. i didn't get your idea of nsdatecomponent. ok i implement the nsdatecomponent but as of my calendar identifier is different from other calendar how should i tell my app right now is user changing the day or not or system time hit midnight. if you could write me the code i appreciated it